# Get key values of nested json objects

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization, org.json

I want to get the values of the keys of the next json file using `org.json` library:

```
{
    "1": {
        "subject1": "MIS",
        "subject2": "DBMS",
        "subject3": "UML"
    },
    "2": {
        "subject1": "ART",
        "subject2": "MATH",
        "subject3": "MUSIC"
    },
    "3": {
        "subject1": "HISTORY",
        "subject2": "CHEMISTY",
        "subject3": "BIOLOGY"
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
package com.company;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"1\": {\"subject1\": \"MIS\",\"subject2\": \"DBMS\",\"subject3\": \"UML\"},\"2\": {\"subject1\": \"ART\",\"subject2\": \"MATH\",\"subject3\": \"MUSIC\"},\"3\": {\"subject1\": \"HISTORY\",\"subject2\": \"CHEMISTY\",\"subject3\": \"BIOLOGY\"}}";

        try{
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray subjects = root.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(i+1));

                for (int j = 0; j < subjects.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject number = subjects.getJSONObject(j);
                    String s1 = number.getString("subject1");
                    String s2 = number.getString("subject2");
                    String s3 = number.getString("subject3");
                    System.out.println(s1+", "+ s2+", "+s3);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With `JSONArray subjects = root.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(i+1));` I thought I was getting:

```
JSONArray subjects = root.getJSONArray("1");
JSONArray subjects = root.getJSONArray("2");
...
```

But that doesn´t work for me. I just get in console the next:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["1"] is not a JSONArray.
    at org.json.JSONObject.wrongValueFormatException(JSONObject.java:2694)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:777)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

And I would like to get:

```
MIS, DBMS, UML
ART, MATH, MUSIC
HISTORI, CHEMISTRY, BIOLOGY
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?
Should I use other library?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Subjects is not an array. Arrays in JSON would be enclosed in `[` and `]`.To get the subjects, you would need follow below approach.

```
try{
     JSONObject root = new JSONObject(json);
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        JSONObject Obj = root.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i+1));
        String s1 = Obj.getString("subject1");
        String s2 = Obj.getString("subject2");
        String s3 = Obj.getString("subject3");
        System.out.println(s1+", "+ s2+", "+s3);
      }
  }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Above JSON when modified like below, would then become an json array
`[{"subject1": "MIS","subject2": "DBMS","subject3": "UML"},{"subject1": "ART","subject2": "MATH","subject3": "MUSIC"},{"subject1": "HISTORY","subject2": "CHEMISTY","subject3": "BIOLOGY"}]`

And then values can be extracted as mentioned below,

```
try{
    JSONArray root = new JSONArray(json);

    for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject Obj = root.getJSONObject(i);
       String s1 = Obj.getString("subject1");
       String s2 = Obj.getString("subject2");
       String s3 = Obj.getString("subject3");
       System.out.println(s1+", "+ s2+", "+s3);
   }
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it all correct until this point

```
JSONArray subjects = root.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(i+1));
```

you have to get `JSONObject` not `JSONArray` since you don't have an array. Your second mistake is this loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < subjects.length(); j++) {}
```

since you're already getting the object manually you don't have to loop.

> Final Code

```
    String json = "{\"1\": {\"subject1\": \"MIS\",\"subject2\": \"DBMS\",\"subject3\": \"UML\"},\"2\": {\"subject1\": \"ART\",\"subject2\": \"MATH\",\"subject3\": \"MUSIC\"},\"3\": {\"subject1\": \"HISTORY\",\"subject2\": \"CHEMISTY\",\"subject3\": \"BIOLOGY\"}}";

    try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject number = root.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i + 1));
            String s1 = number.getString("subject1");
            String s2 = number.getString("subject2");
            String s3 = number.getString("subject3");
            System.out.println(s1 + ", " + s2 + ", " + s3);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> OUTPUT

```
MIS, DBMS, UML
ART, MATH, MUSIC
HISTORY, CHEMISTY, BIOLOGY
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will be lengthy to get data from a file of nested JSON format in Java.

You can use SPL, the open-source Java package, to get this done. It is simple and only one line of code is sufficient:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =json(file("org.json").read()).array() |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as getjsonarray.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st = con.prepareCall("call getjsonarray()");
st.execute();
…
```